# Simple event mechanism

Tags: c++, event-handling

I am working on a simple event mechanism for c++. Since Iam not very experienced I would like to share my code in order to get some thoughts.

I also dont like the BIND_X macros. Ideas how to simplify the binding process are welcome as well any comments regarding problems, bad style...

```
#ifndef EVENTS_H
#define EVENTS_H
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <forward_list>
#include <mutex>

namespace event {
// The type of the source identifier passed to each event listener
typedef const std::string& source_t;

///
/// \brief A handle that identifiers listeners.
///
/// \details Listeners are functions that get called once a event is fired.
/// This struct is used to identify such functions and is used to detach them.
///
struct listener_handle
{
public:
  ///
  /// \brief Create a new handle
  /// \param s  The source
  /// \param h  The handle id
  ///
  listener_handle(source_t s="", int h=0) :
    source(s),
    handle(h)
  { }

  ///
  /// \brief Equals operator
  /// \param other  The handle to compare
  /// \return   True, if the handles are equal
  ///
  bool operator==(const listener_handle& other) const
  {
    return this->source == other.source &&
        this->handle == other.handle;
  }  

  std::string source;
  int handle;
};

template <class... T>
///
/// \brief The event class.
///
class Event
{
public:
  typedef std::function<void(source_t, T...)> func;
  ///
  /// \brief Create new instance
  /// \param source     The name of the event source.
  ///
  Event(source_t source) :
    source(source)
  {}

  ///
  /// \brief Release resources
  ///
  virtual ~Event()
  {
    this->listeners.clear();
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Attach an event
  /// \param newListener The event listener to attach
  /// \return         The handle that may be used to detach the event
  ///
  virtual listener_handle& Attach(const func& newListener)
  {
    this->listeners.push_front(Listener{newListener, this->createListenerHandle()});
    return this->listeners.front().handle;
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Detach an event using its id
  /// \param id The id of the event to detach
  ///
  virtual void Detach(const listener_handle& handle)
  {
    this->listeners.remove_if([handle] (const Listener& l) {return l.handle == handle;});
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Call all listeners
  /// \param argument The EventArgs to send
  ///
  virtual void Invoke(const T&... args) const
  {
    std::for_each(std::begin(this->listeners), std::end(this->listeners), [this, &args...] (const Listener& l) {
      l.listener(this->source, args...);
    });
  }

private:
  struct Listener {
    func listener;
    listener_handle handle;
  };

  ///
  /// \brief Create a random number using per thread local seed.
  /// \return       A random number between int min and int max
  ///
  int createRandom() const
  {
    static std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{
      std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
      std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
    return dist(gen);
  }

  ///
  /// \brief  Create a new listener handle using the registered source name
  /// \return       A new listener handle
  ///
  listener_handle createListenerHandle() const
  {
    return listener_handle{this->source, this->createRandom()};
  }

  std::string source;
  std::forward_list<Listener> listeners;
};

template <typename... T>
///
/// \brief The thread safe event class.
///
/// \details This class should be used if the exposed event may be accessed from multiple threads.
///
class TsEvent : public Event<T...>
{
public:
  ///
  /// \copydoc Event::Event()
  ///
  TsEvent(source_t source): Event<T...>(source)
  { }

  ///
  /// \copydoc Event::~Event()
  ///
  virtual ~TsEvent()
  { }

  ///
  /// \copydoc Event::Attach()
  ///
  virtual listener_handle& Attach(const typename Event<T...>::func& newListener) override
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(this->m);
    return Event<T...>::Attach(newListener);
  }

  ///
  /// \copydoc Event::Detach()
  ///
  virtual void Detach(const listener_handle& handle) override
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(this->m);
    return Event<T...>::Detach(handle);
  }

  ///
  /// \copydoc Event::Invoke()
  ///
  virtual void Invoke(const T&... args) const override
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(this->m);
    return Event<T...>::Invoke(args...);
  }

private:
  std::mutex m;
};
} //event namespace
#endif // EVENTS_H
```

Sample usage (assume CallMe is a static function with 2 parameter):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "event.hpp"
void CallMe(std::string s, int i) {
    std::cout << s << "-" << i << '\n';
}
int main() {
  auto t = new event::Event<int>{"Basic"};
  auto handle = t->Attach(std::function<void(std::string, int)>{CallMe});   
  t->Invoke(5);
  t->Detach(handle);
  delete t;
}
```

Note: The bind macros are used to simplify binding of methods that require some kind of instance so call. Assuming a class s exposes an event e that requires 3 parameter and callMe (defined inside receiver) satisfies this, one may use it like that:

```
auto handle = s->e->Attach(BIND_3(receiver::callMe, r));
```

Edit: Here is an example of how to avoid the BIND_X macros (and that is why i got rid if them)

```
auto handle = s->e->Attach([r](const std::string& s, int a, int b) {r->callMe(s, a, b);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::function` you don't ensure signature matching (It work if argument are just convertible). some kind of function_traits can be applied here.

Try to check at compile time that the signature of the given callback match what you expect.

The loop in `Invoke` can be simplified by using a range-based for loop or `std::for_each`.

You don't have to write `this->` everywhere.

Did you consider using a queue instead of a list? Semantically, it's more correct

The UniqueId generation can be outed from this class, since it's a different concern and maybe reusable.

For your "bind" problem, as callback, user can pass a lambda capturing the instance.

**note**: I modified your "sample" to get it in a working example, but didn't fix the memory leak present in your code original. `new` and `delete` are as an old couple, they never go out without each other.

**edit** : 
I would not have made it possible to inherit the Event class. If it was my class, I would rather opt for a tagged_type so that each event is of a different type, even if signatures matches, even if signatures matches. But this desing choice is a matter of taste.

If you want a better understanding of `function_traits` you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283919/understanding-how-the-function-traits-template-works-in-particular-what-is-the).

Comment: I will look into some way to implement function traits. I dont think a queue is the right data structure since any listener may detach their event at any time. So storing them in a queue doesnt make sense to me. I updated the above code according to your suggestions. (I keep using this-> since it makes it easy to deduce the scope of a variable.)

Comment: Be careful about rules: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Peepe I edited my answer. You'r right for `queues`, I didn't notice this. Try now to outsource the random generator and think about function_traits and my edit. And of course, if I answered your question, do not forget to eventually  tick my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Took a while but a got the function traits working. To make the check actually work I had to remove the inherit argument type from the Attach function and make it a template function itself. (Type conversion would take place before the static_assert inside the function happens)

Maybe I will remove the yet unused part of the function_traits (arity, return type). Not sure about that yet.

event.hpp:

```
namespace event {
// The type of the source identifier passed to each event listener
typedef const std::string& source_t;

template<typename... args>
using func = std::function<void(source_t, args...)>;

///
/// \brief A handle that identifiers listeners.
///
/// \details Listeners are functions that get called once a event is fired.
/// This struct is used to identify such functions and is used to detach them.
///
struct listener_handle
{
public:
  ///
  /// \brief Create a new handle
  /// \param s  The source
  /// \param h  The handle id
  ///
  listener_handle(source_t s="", int h=0) :
    source(s),
    handle(h)
  { }

  ///
  /// \brief Equals operator
  /// \param other  The handle to compare
  /// \return   True, if the handles are equal
  ///
  bool operator==(const listener_handle& other) const
  {
    return this->source == other.source &&
        this->handle == other.handle;
  }  

  std::string source;
  int handle;
};

template <class... T>
///
/// \brief The event class.
///
class Event
{
public:
  ///
  /// \brief Create new instance
  /// \param source     The name of the event source.
  ///
  Event(source_t source) :
    source(source)
  {}

  ///
  /// \brief Release resources
  ///
  ~Event()
  {
    this->listeners.clear();
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Attach an event
  /// \param newListener The event listener to attach
  /// \return         The handle that may be used to detach the event
  ///
  template <class... args>
  listener_handle& Attach(const func<args...>& newListener)
  {
    using listener_traits = ftraits::function_traits<typename std::decay<decltype(newListener)>::type>;
    ftraits::assert_traits_equal<listener_traits, traits>();

    this->listeners.push_front(Listener{newListener, this->createListenerHandle()});
    return this->listeners.front().handle;
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Detach an event using its id
  /// \param id The id of the event to detach
  ///
  void Detach(const listener_handle& handle)
  {
    this->listeners.remove_if([handle] (const Listener& l) {return l.handle == handle;});
  }

  ///
  /// \brief Call all listeners
  /// \param argument The EventArgs to send
  ///
  void Invoke(const T&... args) const
  {
    std::for_each(std::begin(this->listeners), std::end(this->listeners), [this, &args...] (const Listener& l) {
      l.listener(this->source, args...);
    });
  }

private:
  using traits = ftraits::function_traits<func<T...>>;

  struct Listener {
    func<T...> listener;
    listener_handle handle;
  };

  ///
  /// \brief  Create a new listener handle using the registered source name
  /// \return       A new listener handle
  ///
  listener_handle createListenerHandle() const
  {
    return listener_handle{this->source, createRandom()};
  }

  std::string source;
  std::forward_list<Listener> listeners;
};

} //event namespace
```

function_traits.hpp:

```
namespace ftraits {

///
/// \brief Undefined base
///
template<typename>
struct function_traits;

///
/// \brief Specialization for std::function
///
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&Function::operator())>
{ };

///
/// \brief Function traits implementation
///
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const>
{
  typedef ReturnType result_type;

  static constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Arguments);

  template <std::size_t N>
  struct argument
  {
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Arguments...>>::type;
  };
};

template<typename  t1, typename t2>
///
/// \brief Check the the function traits are equal using static assert
///
void assert_traits_equal()
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value, "The function signatures do not match.");
};

}

#endif // FUNCTION_TRAITS_H
```

I also moved the random number generator to a separate header file.

Comment: Great, I really like what it's become!